# Contact php mail page, only sending blank emails.

Tags: php

I am having problems with this contact page, emails are being sent fine but are blank! I cant seem to find a solution. I would of thought $_POST would need to be added, however, the web hosting companies says it is not necessary in this php script  Thankyou for your time and help. Code snippet below.

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "sales@ibdengland.co.uk";
$EmailTo = "kent.collins.uk@gmail.com";
$Subject = "online form";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name']));
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email']));
$Tel = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Tel']));
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Description of project']));
// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  echo "please check your details";
  header("Location: http://www.ibdengland.co.uk/thankyou.html");
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text

$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Tel: ";
$Body .= $Tel;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Description of project: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;URL=thankyou.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;URL=thankyou.html\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the php headers are incorrect. Take a look at this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.

Comment: Does any info come up? Such as subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the headers.

**Example:**

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '. $EmailFrom . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Comment: I would recommend to specify the "FROM:" above the Content-type (may prevent the mail from going to spambox), and headers could be furtherly extended. @ Poster: try these headers out and give us feedback.

Comment: I added the headers to the form but still receiving blank emails.

Comment: Thankyou for the help, but I wrote another script and you will be glad to hear I included some headers, it now works fine. Just need to sort out the formatting. @Akatosh

Answer (score 0):

you have not use any `header`.

take help from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). and use it. I think it will help you.

post header like below

```
$headers = 'From:'.$EmailFrom . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$EmailFrom . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

then replace below

```
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");
```

with the below code

```
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers);
```

plz try this one. and inform me if this work or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Try changing:**

```
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");
```

**To:**

```
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <".$EmailFrom.">");
```